# How to check if input name is inside an array in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I want to know how I can check if input name is equal to name inside an array.
I have multiple inputs like below code:

```
<div class="inputMain">
    <input name="first_name" value="">
</div>
<div class="inputMain">
    <input name="last_name" value="">
</div>
<div class="inputMain">
    <input name="email" value="">
</div>
```

And I have an array Like this:

```
var array = ['last_name', 'email'];
```

I want to add class to div, that wrap the input his name inside the array.
I don't want to use 2 loops.

Comment: `Array.indexOf()`, `Array.includes()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
var inputs = $("input");
var array = ['last_name', 'email'];
  inputs.each(function(){
    if(array.indexOf($(this).attr("name")) >= 0){
      alert($(this).attr("name")+" exists");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputMain">
    <input name="first_name" value="">
</div>
<div class="inputMain">
    <input name="last_name" value="">
</div>
<div class="inputMain">
    <input name="email" value="">
</div>
```

The HTML to the code is same as used by you in your question, I have added a bit of JQuery, that is simple to understand.

I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> check output in browser console:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = ['last_name', 'email', 'dsfdsfds'];
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    var x = document.getElementsByName(element);
    console.log(x);
  });
});

//check output in browser console
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="inputMain">
  <input name="first_name" value="">
</div>
<div class="inputMain">
  <input name="last_name" value="">
</div>
<div class="inputMain">
  <input name="email" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is your solution :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var array = ['last_name', 'email'];
      var inputs = $("div[class='inputMain']").find("input");

      array.forEach(function(name) {
        inputs.each(function (x){
          if (inputs[x].name === name) {
            inputs[x].parentNode.classList.add("myClass")
          }
        });
      });

      console.log(inputs.prevObject);

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/12es37ko/62/

you can check result into browser console :)